# Listening to uniswap for transactions, need to add a nonce filter

Tags: transactions

I'm here looking to watch Uniswap (or any DEX) transactions and detect whenever an interesting transaction goes through with a newly created wallet nonce = 0, or close to it).  How can I add further logic to check the nonce value of tx.from.

Code below. Cheers

```
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "wss://ethereum-mainnet.core.chainstack.com/ws/73db9b970cc38bbba958f73c9d28bef0";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

const UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D";
const SWAP_EXACT_ETH_FOR_TOKENS_SIGNATURE = "0x7ff36ab5";
const SWAP_EXACT_ETH_FOR_FEE_TOKENS_SIGNATURE = "0xb6f9de95";
// Implementing this on the new V3 universal router would require the commands Execute parameter to be decoded

async function subscribeToNewBlocks() {
  try {
    const subscription = await web3.eth.subscribe("newBlockHeaders");
    subscription.on("connected", handleConnected);
    subscription.on("data", handleNewBlock);
    subscription.on("error", handleError);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error subscribing to new blocks: ${error}`);
  }
}

function handleConnected(subscriptionId) {
  console.log(`New subscription: ${subscriptionId}`);
}

async function handleNewBlock(blockHeader) {
  try {
    console.log(`Got new block: ${blockHeader.number}`);
    const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockHeader.number, true);
    block.transactions.forEach((tx) => {
      if (tx.to && tx.to.toLowerCase() === UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS.toLowerCase() && (tx.input.startsWith(SWAP_EXACT_ETH_FOR_TOKENS_SIGNATURE) || tx.input.startsWith(SWAP_EXACT_ETH_FOR_FEE_TOKENS_SIGNATURE))) {
        console.log("Incoming swap transaction: " + tx.hash);
        console.log(`From: ${tx.from}`);
        console.log(`Value: ${web3.utils.fromWei(tx.value, "ether")} ETH`);
        console.log("--------------------------------");
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error fetching block transactions: ${error}`);
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  console.error(`Error receiving new blocks: ${error}`);
}

subscribeToNewBlocks();
```

Answer (score 0):

The transaction has a `nonce` field that contains the nonce used by `from` to sign it.

To get the count of signed transaction by an address use `getTransactionCount`.